# How often iAd banner send request?

Tags: ios, iad

Is it known how often iAd banner sends requests? I.e. if my app sent 2000 request for how long time the app has been used?

Comment: Each time your banner ad is created it sends a request. Also, the refresh rate is 30 seconds. So every 30 seconds a new request is sent for a new ad. Calculating application usage time based on request amounts will be a complete guess. If it was one user with 2000 requests you could say that user used the application for 16.6 hours. (2000 requests>2 requests a minute>1000 minutes>16.6~ Hours). The issue with using requests to estimate usage times is that maybe 2000 users just launched your application, received one ad, and then closed your application resulting in a usage time of mere seconds.

Comment: but if I decrease the request time the app download time that is already  a more expressive number